# Generating NPV estimates in Powerquery for PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

So I am looking to generate NPVs for a number of different cases. Assume the discount rate is 10%.

Below is some sample data and I was hoping to get NPVs for all cases both for costs and for revenues.

So in this case, what would be ideal is to get:

-Neptune & Mars NPV Revenues

-Neptune & Mars NPV Costs

Ideally, in different tables ie. NPV cost table with all projects and the NPVs of each their costs and the same for the revenue NPV table.
Hope you can help.

| Case | Profile | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Neptune | Cost | 2021 | 7 |
| Neptune | Cost | 2022 | 7 |
| Neptune | Cost | 2023 | 5 |
| Neptune | Cost | 2024 | 6 |
| Neptune | Revenue | 2021 | 7 |
| Neptune | Revenue | 2022 | 7 |
| Neptune | Revenue | 2023 | 5 |
| Neptune | Revenue | 2024 | 6 |
| Mars | Cost | 2021 | 6 |
| Mars | Cost | 2022 | 6 |
| Mars | Cost | 2023 | 6 |
| Mars | Cost | 2024 | 8 |
| Mars | Revenue | 2021 | 7 |
| Mars | Revenue | 2022 | 7 |
| Mars | Revenue | 2023 | 5 |
| Mars | Revenue | 2024 | 6 |

Comment: What does NPV stand for?

Comment: net present value. The typical excel formula to use is NPV(discount rate, value array)

Comment: Would a calculated column work then? So Value * 0.9?
Then you can show either revenue or cost in your visuals/dashboard by filtering on visual level